# change color in strings.xml and onClick method

Tags: android, string, layout

Hi this is my strings.xml.

```
<item><font color ="red">mnasekundę</font></item>
```

I changed color of item  to red, but unfortunately **LogCat say that: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick**
And this is my OnCick method:

```
    public void konwertuj(View view) {

    if (fromEditText.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
        Toast.makeText(GlownaPredkosc.this, "Musisz wpisać dowolną liczbę", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        // Get the string from the Spinners and number from the EditText

        String fromString = (String) fromSpinner.getSelectedItem();
        String toString = (String) toSpinner.getSelectedItem();
        double input = Double.valueOf(fromEditText.getText().toString());

        // Convert the strings to something in our Unit enu,
        KonwerterPredkosc.Jednostka fromJednostka = KonwerterPredkosc.Jednostka.fromString(fromString);
        KonwerterPredkosc.Jednostka toJednostka = KonwerterPredkosc.Jednostka.fromString(toString);

        // Create a converter object and convert!
        KonwerterPredkosc konwerter = new KonwerterPredkosc(fromJednostka, toJednostka);
        double result = konwerter.convert(input);
        toEditText.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
```

P.S When font color is black, everything works great.

Thanks for reading

complete output:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannedString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                                        at com.example.barto.konwerter2.GlownaPredkosc.konwertuj(GlownaPredkosc.java:73)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: please add complete logcat output...

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
`toEditText.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));`
without changing anything in .xml.